# How do I design rest controller with spring webflux so it is non-blocking?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

this is my first time trying to utilize Webflux. I have a controller that returns Mono object like this:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/{resourceType}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<String> getData(@NotBlank @PathVariable ResourceType resourceType) {
        return resourceService.getResource(resourceType);

    }
```

In the resourceService, I am creating an object using `resourceType` and want to build a string by calling another endpoint something like this:

```
    @Override
    public Mono<String> getResource(ResourceType resourceType) {
        Mono<ServerCredential> credentialMono = credentialService.getServerCredential(resourceType);
        //want to call an endpoint using WebClient to receive response and return that response back to controller layer
    }
```

If I subscribe to `credentialMono` to call endpoint like this:

```
credentialMono.subscribe(credential -> callApi(credential));
```

I am not sure if this can return anything back to the caller. I would like to return `Mono<String>` object back to controller and this `Mono<String>` object will be received from api call something like this:

```
private Mono<String> searchResource(ServerCredential credential) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(credential.getServer().getServerUrl());
        return client.post()
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .retry(RETRY_COUNT)
    }
```

It is not working code, but something like this. I want to call this method from `Mono<ServerCredential> credentialMono = credentialService.getServerCredential(resourceType);` and essentially return back response to controller. How can I achieve this? Am I even going into the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to call `subscribe()`

Just continue your reactive chain using `flatMap()` operator:

```
public Mono<String> getResource(ResourceType resourceType) {
    return credentialService.getServerCredential(resourceType)
            .flatMap(credential -> searchResource(credential));
}

private Mono<String> searchResource(ServerCredential credential) {
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(credential.getServer().getServerUrl());
    return client.post()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .retry(RETRY_COUNT);
}
```

Your `searchResource()` method would be called when `getServerCredential(resourceType)` emitted the value.